# Eclipse when read a big file doesnt work - Java

Tags: java, eclipse

i need some help because i am stucked. 
    I just made a program in Java which reads a file line by line, does some calculations and prints the resuls. For instance, if I have 60 lines in my csv file it will print 60000 results.The problem is that when i have 100 lines it works fine, when i have 1000 (the program in this occassion will print 100000 values) it returns only 100000 zeros.
 What would be the problem?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class WillemainApp {
    static String delimiter = ",";
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String sCurrentLine;
            // read the file and store each line in an object
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Book2.csv"));
            int [] Demand = new int[36];
            int [] LeadTime = new int[1000];
            List<Materials> materials = new ArrayList<Materials>();
            List<LeadTimeDemand> lead = new ArrayList<LeadTimeDemand>();
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String [] fields = sCurrentLine.split(delimiter);
                for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                    Demand[i] = Integer.parseInt(fields[i]);
                    if (Demand[i] < 0) {
                        Demand[i] = 0;
                    }           
                }
                materials.add(new Materials(Demand));
            }           
            for (Materials m :materials) {
                for(int f = 0; f < LeadTime.length; f++) {
                    LeadTime[f] = 0;
                }
                // some preperations in order to define some parameters of the problem
                double ZeroToZero = 0;
                double ZeroToNonZero = 0;
                double NonZeroToZero = 0;
                double NonZeroToNonZero = 0;
                int [] materialdemand = m.getDemand();
                int countzero = 0;
                for (int v =0; v < materialdemand.length; v++) {
                    if (materialdemand[v] >0) {
                        countzero++;
                    }
                }
                int NonZeroValues[] = new int [countzero];
                int q = 0;
                for(int e = 0; e < materialdemand.length; e++) {
                    if (materialdemand[e] != 0) {
                        NonZeroValues[q] = materialdemand[e];
                        q++;
                    }
                }
                int [] forecastsequence = new int [materialdemand.length];
                for(int j = 0; j < materialdemand.length - 1; j++) {
                      if ((materialdemand[j] == 0) && (materialdemand[j + 1] == 0)) {     
                          ZeroToZero = ZeroToZero + 1;
                      } 
                      if ((materialdemand[j] == 0) && (materialdemand[j + 1] != 0)) {     
                          ZeroToNonZero = ZeroToNonZero + 1 ;
                      }
                      if ((materialdemand[j] != 0) && (materialdemand[j + 1] == 0)) {
                          NonZeroToZero = NonZeroToZero + 1;
                      }
                      if ((materialdemand[j] != 0) && (materialdemand[j + 1] != 0)) {
                          NonZeroToNonZero = NonZeroToNonZero + 1;
                      }
                }
                double ZeroToZeroInterval = (ZeroToZero / (ZeroToZero + ZeroToNonZero)) * 100;
                double ZeroToNonZeroInterval =  (ZeroToNonZero / (ZeroToZero + ZeroToNonZero)) * 100;
                double NonZeroToZeroInterval = (NonZeroToZero / (NonZeroToZero + NonZeroToNonZero)) * 100;
                double NonZeroToNonZeroInterval = (NonZeroToNonZero / (NonZeroToZero + NonZeroToNonZero)) * 100;
                if (ZeroToZeroInterval == ZeroToNonZeroInterval) {
                    ZeroToZeroInterval = ZeroToZeroInterval - 0.1;
                }
                if (NonZeroToZeroInterval == NonZeroToNonZeroInterval) {
                    NonZeroToZeroInterval = NonZeroToZeroInterval - 0.1;
                }
                double min = 0;
                int kal = 0;
                if (ZeroToZeroInterval < ZeroToNonZeroInterval) {
                      min = ZeroToZeroInterval;
                } else {
                    min = ZeroToNonZeroInterval;
                }
                double min2 = 0;
                if (NonZeroToZeroInterval < NonZeroToNonZeroInterval) {
                    min2 = NonZeroToZeroInterval;
                } else {
                    min2 = NonZeroToNonZeroInterval;
                }
                while (kal <1000) {
                      forecastsequence[0] = materialdemand[0];
                      for (int w = 1; w < forecastsequence.length; w++) {
                          forecastsequence[w] = 0;
                      }
                  for (int z = 0; z < materialdemand.length - 1; z++) {
                      Random rn = new Random();
                      int random = rn.nextInt(101);
                      if (materialdemand[z] == 0) {       
                          if ((random > min) && (min == ZeroToZeroInterval)) {
                              forecastsequence[z + 1] = NonZeroValues[rn.nextInt(NonZeroValues.length)];
                          }
                          if ((random > min) && (min == ZeroToNonZeroInterval)) {
                              forecastsequence[z + 1] = 0;
                          }
                          if ((random < min) && (min == ZeroToZeroInterval)) {
                              forecastsequence[z + 1] = 0;
                          }
                          if ((random < min) && (min == ZeroToNonZeroInterval)) {
                              forecastsequence[z + 1] = NonZeroValues[rn.nextInt(NonZeroValues.length)];
                          }
                      }
                      if (materialdemand[z] != 0) {
                          if ((random < min2) && (min2 == NonZeroToZeroInterval)) {
                              forecastsequence[z + 1] = 0;
                          }
                          if ((random < min2) && (min2 == NonZeroToNonZeroInterval)) {
                              forecastsequence[z + 1] = NonZeroValues[rn.nextInt(NonZeroValues.length)];
                          }
                          if ((random > min2) && (min2 == NonZeroToZeroInterval)) {
                              forecastsequence[z + 1] = NonZeroValues[rn.nextInt(NonZeroValues.length)];

                          }
                          if ((random >min2) && (min2 == NonZeroToNonZeroInterval)) {
                              forecastsequence[z + 1] = 0;
                          }               
                      }
                  }   
                  for (int p = 0; p < forecastsequence.length; p++) {
                    if (forecastsequence[p] != 0) { 
                        int JITTERED = (int) (1 + forecastsequence[p] + 0.5 * Math.sqrt(forecastsequence[p]));
                        forecastsequence[p] = JITTERED;         
                    }
                  }
                  int [] LeadTimeDemand = new int [forecastsequence.length - 1];
                  for (int ram = 0; ram < LeadTimeDemand.length; ram++) {
                      LeadTimeDemand[ram] = 0;
                  }
                  int sum = 0;
                  for (int d = 0; d < LeadTimeDemand.length;d++) {  
                      LeadTimeDemand[d] = forecastsequence[d] + forecastsequence[d+1];
                      sum = sum + LeadTimeDemand[d];      
                  }
                  LeadTime[kal] = sum;
                  kal++;
                  System.out.println(sum);    
                }



             } 
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There must be something wrong with your code.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the file?  Why are you using eclipse to view CSV?

Comment: There is no problem with the code. Thats for sure. It doenst work when i have a big file.

Comment: edit the question and post your code and snippet of the file.

Comment: If there's no problem with the code, then you're on the wrong site. Maybe try  [Telepathic Love Therapy](http://www.vibrational-alchemy.com/telepathic/intro.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the encoding of the file ! 
Open the file in BBEdit or TextWrangler*.
Set the file as Unicode (UTF-16 Little-Endian) (Line Endings can be Unix or Windows). Save!
In Excel: Data > Get External Data > Import Text File...

The source of the problem can be the wrong encoding.